# Method doesn't update variable globally?

Tags: java, methods, global-variables

So, in the beginning of my java class I define globally:
`static long world;`.
Then I have several functions using `world` as an argument. One of theses, called setCell does not work as intended, and I can't figure out why. I have tried error searching with println commands, so now my code looks like this:

```
public static long setCell(long world, int col, int row, boolean newval){
    if(col>= 0 && col<8 && row>=0 && row<8){
      int bitPosition = col + 8*row;
      long newWorld = PackedLong.set(world, bitPosition, newval);
      System.out.println(newWorld);
      world = newWorld;
      System.out.println(world);
      return world;
    }
    else{
      return world;
    }
}
```

The main idea of the code is, that it should update `world` by changing one of its bits with the `PackedLong.set` method (which is working well) and then return the new updated `world`.

If we now run:

```
world =0x20A0600000000000L;
System.out.println(world);
setCell(world, 1, 1, true);
System.out.println(world);
```

in the main method, we get the following output:

`2350984558603665408
2350984558603665920
2350984558603665920
2350984558603665408`

From this I have concluded that the commands inside the `setCell` method works as intended, but that the method does not change `world` "globally" through the whole code. How can I solve this issue?
Many Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the parameter `world`

```
public static long setCell(long world, int col, int row, boolean newval)
```

This will hide the global variable and instead update the parameter.  You should avoid names the hide other variables that are present in the same scope.  Instead choose a different name for the parameter.

Comment: This is correct, but how would you _fix_ the problem?

Comment: Use a parameter name that doesn't hide the global variable.

Comment: @Kelvin Thank you for your answer! Could you please just be a little more specific about exactly where I should change my variable? I tried writing `static long initialWorld` in the beginning, changing `world`to `initialWorld` everywhere in the main method and not changing anything in `setCell`, but the error still persists.

Comment: when you are referring to the global variable it would be `initialWorld` and when you are referring to the parameter it should be `world`.  Which ones to change depends on what your goal is.  I would guess that you would leave `PackedLong.set(world, bitPosition, newval);` the same, and change others to `initialWorld`

Comment: @Kelvin now when I proceed with my program I see that `public static long setCell(long world, int col, int row, boolean newval){
  if(col>= 0 && col<8 && row>=0 && row<8){
  int bitPosition = col + 8*row;
  long newWorld = PackedLong.set(world, bitPosition, newval);
  initialWorld = newWorld;
  System.out.println(initialWorld);
  return initialWorld;
  }
  else{
   return world;
  }
 }` was probably not the ideal solution, because the rest of the program won't work well. Is there any way I could make it return `world` instead of `initialWorld`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is bad to use global variables, because they are a *hidden dependency*. It will be unclear if a class is using `world`, unless you actually go and find it being used in the code. Code like that can be hard to debug.

`long` does not have this method to set some bit on it, instead of passing it to some static function, and it updating some global variable (a la C), you would be better off encapsulation it in a class that offers this functionality:

```
class World {
    private long world;

    public World(long value) {
        this.world = value;
    }

    public void setCell(int col, int row, boolean newval) {
        if(col>= 0 && col<8 && row>=0 && row<8){
            int bitPosition = col + 8*row;
            world = PackedLong.set(world, bitPosition, newval);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(world); // Or print a hexadecimal presentation.
    }
}
```

Classes allow you to make plain data (like `long`) *smart*. It also allows you to remove a parameter (since it's kept internally).

It will also be much clearer that you're changing `world`:

```
World world = new World(0x20A0600000000000L);
System.out.println(world);
world.setCell(1, 1, true); // Aha, 'world' is being altered
System.out.println(world);
```

---

Kelvin has the right answer for why *your* code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Jorn Vernee's answer is the best one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39561744/4506528

However I'll answer your question with an **extremely bad coding practice** demonstrating how you can achieve this with the language features. If your class is well made, you should **never** have to do this.

If your class is called `Story` and a static field called `world`, you can directly reference it from *most* places using `Story.world`. This includes re-assigning it.

```
public class Story {
    public static String world = "Saturn";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doStuff("Earth");
        System.out.println(world);
    }

    public static void doStuff(String world) {
        Story.world = "Europa";
        world = "Mars";
    }
}
```

Even though this provides an answer to your question, **I do not encourage using static fields this way**. Please do not put this answer into practice.

---

- Your `long` is meant to behave in a very specific way: Its behavior should be encapsulated into a class.
- Do not use static fields to describe the state of your system.
- Change the parameter name of your method to avoid confusion when reading the code.